# Do I need to record search results in SQLite?

Tags: android

I'm following the method described by  [Virgil Dobjanschi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE), but I'm not sure what to do in this scenario:

**I want users to be able to search brands and models of vehicles
by typing their name in a auto complete text view.**

Considering this scenario, I have some questions:

1 - As Virgil Dobjanschi recomends, resources returned by the
rest api should be recorded in SQLite. In this case, should I record
these search results ?

2 - If yes, when should I load this data from SQLite ? Do I need
to find for matches first in SQLite and after that call the rest
api for aditional results ?

Comment: it would really depend on how server independent you want your app to be. you might consider embedding data to your app from the start or do a timely db sync. if your data doesn't change that much, syncing in the background would be your best bet. Remember, you are creating an app, not a website. bulk syncing saves battery life when on 3G.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Models of car don't change that much, brands less than that. Syncing data while the app is being istalled is probably the best aproach. We're using sync adapter. Should be easy to update models and brands whenever they change. Please, write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would really depend on how server independent you want your app to be. you might consider embedding data to your app from the start or do a timely db sync. if your data doesn't change that much, syncing in the background would be your best bet. Remember, you are creating an app, not a website. bulk syncing saves battery life when on 3G.